# Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net in the access logs

Tags: log-files

```
54.204.131.75 - - [09/Jul/2014:17:53:43 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 283 "-" "Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net"
```

A new line in my access log the other day. As far as i can tell this is most likely a phishing scam. Does anyone know if I might be wrong.

I can see little more trace on my machine of any damage. The log was recorded 3 time over the course of an hour or so.

Comment: What happened when you emailed them?

Comment: I gave him my bank account details and he robbed me blind ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like somebody's robot accessing the HTTP server on your machine. My gut says it's probably harmless. [Searching Google for those keyword](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdrlabs+cloud+mapping) returns other people who are seeing it in their logs, too.

It's good to be vigilant and it's good to hear that you're watching your logs so closely. In this case, I suspect you're alright.

Comment: I did a lot of searching on it too but could not find anything conclusive. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I setup an enabled Fail2Ban and saw this in my logs because I'm blocking the HEAD method. Best to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is suspicious they have nothing about their company or their project on their site.  To me it looks like a way to hide their scanning under a reasonable facade of respectability.

Comment: interesting point. Add a three letter Acronym, followed by "labs".